# ng-bootstrap datepicker formControl minDate maxDate

Tags: ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

When setting [minDate] and [maxDate] it sets not only to datepicker, but also on `<input>`. I want to set minDate and/or maxDate to datepicker which works, but the problem is at the moment when user types in invalid date by hand(that is greater or smaller than min/max date). After this invalid input I want to show red colored text that it is an invalid date, but datepicker clears ngModel value. Does anyone knows how to stop datepicker from deleting date?

```
<input class="form-control form-control-model" name="dp" type="text" autocomplete="off"
               [(ngModel)]="date"
               (ngModelChange)="onDateInputChange($event)"
               #d="ngbDatepicker"
               ngbDatepicker
               [minDate]="dateToNgbDate(_startDate, false)"
               [maxDate]="dateToNgbDate(_endDate, true)"
               (click)="d.open()"
               (dateSelect)="onDatepickerDateSelect($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue myself by closing datepicker manualy on valid date input. In that way datepicker cant start doing anything with the value. (dateSelect)="d.close"